# Dichotomous management vs. changing management vs. differential management?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to ask a question related to management of natural resources.

Let's say that in one area *more management approaches have been used during the last decades. Sometimes even contrary to each other.* Maybe the term *'chaotic'* would be good, but I think the term *'chaos'* should be used when the system is chaotic. Whereas in this case, it was caused by human interactions with the natural systems.

If I would like to describe this time period as one event, should I use the term **changing management strategies**? I.e. it was not the same throughout this period.

Or should I use **differential management strategies**?, i.e. it changed according to some other conditions.

I suppose that the term **dichotomous management** is only for two contradicting events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really uncertain about what your context actually is about. But I'll provide you with a few possible words you could use for *'changing strategies'*.

> - Altering Strategies
> - Varying Strategies
> - Shifting Strategies

Answer (score 1):

... a **confusion** of management strategies ...

2. A situation in which things are messy, badly organized, or not clear.

  
http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/confusion#confusion__2